# svn checkout: Network is unreachable

Tags: svn

I have a strange problem, when trying to checkout googletest I get this:

```
svn checkout https://googletest.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ googletest-read-only
svn: E000101: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://googletest.googlecode.com /svn/trunk'
svn: E000101: Error running context: Network is unreachable
```

same for http:

```
svn checkout http://googletest.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ googletest-read-only
svn: E000101: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://googletest.googlecode.com /svn/trunk'
svn: E000101: Error running context: Network is unreachable
```

but those svn repositories work:

```
svn checkout svn://svn.lighttpd.net/lighttpd/trunk/ lighttpd
svn checkout http://svn.wikimedia.org/svnroot/mediawiki/trunk/phase3
```

also I can reach the googletest svn repository using firefox, as anyone an idea what could cause this?
I am running Arch Linux with

```
svn --version
svn, version 1.8.9 (r1591380)
compiled May 29 2014, 02:47:25 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

**Solution**: it was a problem with my ipv6 connection, the other repositories worked because they use ipv4

Comment: Maybe a firewall is blocking access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have problems with connectivity at your side, not SVN per se: "Network is unreachable". Samples with another repos in another nets are irrelevant

```
>svn ls http://googletest.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/
CHANGES
CMakeLists.txt
CONTRIBUTORS
LICENSE
Makefile.am
README
build-aux/
cmake/
codegear/
configure.ac
include/
m4/
make/
msvc/
samples/
scripts/
src/
test/
xcode/
```

Comment: svn ls http://googletest.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/                                                         
svn: E000101: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://googletest.googlecode.com/svn/trunk'
svn: E000101: Error running context: Network is unreachable
ping googletest.googlecode.com works though... I don't think it is a network problem

Comment: okay it was indeed a network problem, my ipv6 connection was not working